# Java OutOfMemoryError Using Picasso Image

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, picasso

I am trying to load an image into an ImageView and am receiving an OutOfMemoryError. The image displays dynamically based on the specific view in the ViewPager. However, after I keep scrolling through the ViewPager, the image eventually fails to load and causes an OutOfMemoryError.

Note that I have 4 View in the ViewPager, and the app appears to crash on View 2. I am guessing the image is simply to large in size, but I was under the impression that Picasso handles accordingly:

Picasso Code:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
    .load(mImageURL)
    .fit()
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .into((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.comments_image));
```

XML

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/comments_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".525"
    android:background="@color/black">
</ImageView>
```

Error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 5074572 byte allocation with 132096 free bytes and 129KB until OOM
     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:812)
     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:789)
     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:756)
     at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.createCachedBitmapIfNeeded(VectorDrawable.java:713)
     at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.draw(VectorDrawable.java:280)
     at com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable.draw(PicassoDrawable.java:105)
     at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1176)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15231)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14167)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14167)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1131)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2341)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14167)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1373)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(F
```

Comment: What's the resolution of the image?

Comment: I know it is 359.2 KB and that it is simply just too large, however I was hoping to understand how Picasso can compress to prevent this error. The image is located here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/fan-polls/Durant.jpg

Comment: As I understood a while ago, it has more to do with the resolution that it does with the size. I'm not well acquainted with Picasso, tho I heard of it. Someone else might be able to help you better, hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made android:largeheap="true" in your manifiest file?

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="MyApplication"
    android:largeHeap="true"*
    android:logo="@drawable/logo_for_up"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

Comment: What does this actually do, can you help me understand before I implement it?

Comment: Applications running on API Level 11+ can have android:largeHeap="true" on the <application> element in the manifest to request a larger-than-normal heap size, and getLargeMemoryClass() on ActivityManager will tell you how big that heap is.

Comment: However there is no guarantee how large the large heap will be.

The user will perceive your large-heap request, because it will force their other apps out of RAM terminate other apps' processes to free up system RAM for use by your large heap.

Comment: Use glide and don't even bother yourself with any large heap. Also.. using large heap affect the Garbage collector so the app will be slower.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), since it is designed to work well on low-cost (and worst hardware) devices by default.

A great difference between Picasso and Glide is that Glide's default format is `RGB_565` when Picasso's `ARGB_8888`. As you can see below, it costs 50% less memory than Picasso to do the same job.

[Memory cost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gCyP.png)

Still, if you aren't up to change your library, you can try resizing your image on Picasso's builder by using `.resize(int, int)` method.

Comment: I noticed that the error is occurring on a Samsung emulator, but the HTC emulator I am also running is having no issues.

Comment: I am interested in setting a max size of 100Kb, any idea on how I would go about doing that?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve that with Picasso since it would have to calculate which size (combination of width and height) will produce a maximum of 100Kb in your memory.

Comment: I definitely cannot use another library. I use Picasso for some image modification and it is essential to my app.

Comment: But I didn't asked you only to change your library. Read the "Still..." paragraph.

Comment: Still, if there's no other way to optimize the memory use with this library, the question should be closed.

Comment: I switch from Picasso to Glide I even been able to remove the Large heap usage. It works like a charm.